# How to read from a Linux serial port

Tags: linux, serial-port

I am working on robot which has to control using wireless serial communication. The robot is running on a microcontroller (by burning a .hex file). I want to control it using my Linux ([Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29)) PC. I am new to serial port programming. I am able to send the data, but I am not able to read data.

A few piece of code which is running over at the microcontroller:

Function to send data:

```
void TxData(unsigned char tx_data)
{
    SBUF = tx_data;  // Transmit data that is passed to this function
    while(TI == 0)   // Wait while data is being transmitted
        ;
}
```

I am sending data through an array of characters data_array[i]:

```
  for (i=4; i<=6; i++)
  {
      TxData(data_array[i]);
      RI = 0;              // Clear receive interrupt. Must be cleared by the user.
      TI = 0;        // Clear transmit interrupt. Must be cleared by the user.
  }
```

Now the piece of code from the C program running on Linux...

```
while (flag == 0) {
    int res = read(fd, buf, 255);
    buf[res] = 0; /* Set end of string, so we can printf */
    printf(":%s:%d\n", buf, res);
    if (buf[0] == '\0')
        flag = 1;
}
```

It prints out value of **res = 0**.

Actually I want to read data *character-by-character* to perform calculations and take further decision. Is there another way of doing this?

Note: Is there good study material (code) for serial port programming on Linux?

How can I read from the Linux serial port...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, take a look at */proc/tty/driver/serial* to see that everything is set up correctly (i.e., you see the signals you should see). Then, have a look at the manual page for [termios(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/termios), you may be interested in the VMIN and VTIME explanation.

Answer (score 3):

This is a good guide: *[Serial Programming Guide for POSIX Operating Systems](http://www.c-program.com/pdf/serialPort_Programming_c.pdf)*

The read call may return with no data and *errno* set to *EAGAIN*.  You need to check the return value and loop around to read again if you're expecting data to arrive.

Comment: Thanks amardeep for ur help. I need one more favor plz. actually what I am doing is sending the  whiteline sensor's(left, middle, right) value(which keeps on changing) and at other end receiving them. Can u help me in receiving these values in array so I can store them in different variables and then do computation. Also there is problem in synchronization like in above sending code I am only receiving value of data_array[6] always , it is not showing other 2 values. Is there a way to synchronize them and correctly receive them in an array or in 3 different variables?